# C++ skipping bytes when reading from a binary file

Tags: c++, io, binaryfiles

I put together some C++ code to extract PNGs from certain files. It's not the most refined, but it seems to be skipping over certain null bytes.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream source("source.win", ios::out | ios::binary);
    char current[] = { 0,0,0,0 };
    char header[] = { (char)137, 'P', 'N', 'G' };
    char footer[] = { 'I', 'E', 'N', 'D' };
    char c = 0;
    int n = 0;
    ofstream out("png0.png", ios::out | ios::binary);
    out.close();
    while (source >> c) {
        if (out.is_open()) {
            out << c;
        }
        current[0] = current[1];
        current[1] = current[2];
        current[2] = current[3];
        current[3] = c;
        if (current[0] == (char)137 &&
            current[1] == 'P' &&
            current[2] == 'N' &&
            current[3] == 'G') {
            n++;
            out.open("png" + to_string(n) + ".png", 6);
            out << (char)137 << "PNG";
        }
        if (current[0] == 'I' &&
            current[1] == 'E' &&
            current[2] == 'N' &&
            current[3] == 'D') {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the beginning of a file that it outputs, and the beginning of the actual file it should output:

```
89 50 4E 47 1A 00 00 00 49 48 44 52 00 00 01 00
00 00 01 00 08 06 00 00 00 5C 72 A8 66 00 00 5F
49 44 41 54 78 9C ED DD 6F 88 65 75 ...
```

vs.

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52
00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00 08 06 00 00 00 5C 72 A8
66 00 00 0A 5F 49 44 41 54 78 9C ED DD 6F 88 65
75 ...
```

Edit: I switched from >> to get() and from << to put(), but `0A` is still being put as `0D 0A`

Comment: Unrelated: No need to specify `ios::out` to either constructor. If you're reading with an `ifstream`, you're not going to be writing so there's no need for `out`. In the output file, the direction is implied by having an `ofstream`.

Comment: `while (source >> c)` is trying to read formatted input from a binary file. Generally not a good idea because formatted reads default to skipping whitespace.. Probably part of the problem you are experiencing. Consider using `get `instead. Also consider using `uint8_t` or `std::byte` instead of `char` when reading binary data.

Comment: I've forgotten once again that I can answer questions as well as comment.

Comment: using get() and switching to bytes fixed most of it, but now `0A` is being read as `0D0A`. Is there a way to fix this without having to write code to delete the extra bytes?

Comment: Odd. Opening the file in binary mode should have taken care of that for you already.

Comment: Ah, but maybe not if you're still `out << c;` ing. Use `put` here.

Comment: I need to mess with << a bit more to confirm the above assertion. I'm having trouble duplicating that.

Answer (score 1):

The program isn't dropping nulls, it's dropping whitespace characters. This is because the default behavior of `operator>>` is to discard whitespace. Note how the `0A`s (line feed) and `0D`s (carriage return) have been stripped out. You should also also find `20` (space), `0C` (form feed), `09` (tab), and  `08` (vertical tab) are also missing.

The hack fix is to add [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) (ie `source >> std::noskipws >> c`) to instruct the stream to not skip whitespace. But the better approach is to not make formatted reads and writes in the first place, prefer [`std::istream::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) and [`std::ostream::put()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/put) instead.

That said, once you find the beginning of the region of interest, you should consider switching to [`std::istream::read()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) and [`std::ostream::write()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write) to move whole blocks of multiple bytes at a time.